# Webserver on Pi 3 works, but not on pi 0W

Tags: pi-3, ssh, pi-zero-w, web-server

So I have a bit of a doozy here. I have a webserver that works on my pi 3, and on the pi 3, it also can SSH. But once I power off, and put my SD card into my pi zero w, the webserver doesn't work, I can't ping off it, and SSH returns an error.

When I go through my browser to the suspected webpage, it returns this: Unable to connect

When I SSH, it sends this: No route to host

And for the Ping, it says: From 192.168.2.17 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

And goes on 10 pings later...

Again it works on the Pi 3, but not the zero. Any other info I need to give? And what could cause this?

Comment: It seems that SD card either doesn't boot or doesn't initialize the network on the zero.

Comment: It does boot, I have a camera, and it has a light once it is recording, which turns on. How would I deal with a pi that doesn't initialize the network?

Comment: Attach a screen and a keyboard and look at the network status and error messages in the log files.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Slight problem, I only have the mini-HDMI adapter, not the micro USB one. So if I use my pi 3, would I be able to see the old logs from the pi zero? Or do they get overwritten every time I power off the pi?

Comment: Do you use hostname or IP address to access the Pi? If IP: are you sure you use the correct address? If you use DHCP then I would expect the IP address for Pi3 and Pi0 to be different because MAC address is different

Comment: I use the IP address, but you see, the router ends up giving it the same IP address when I look at the router's web page, that was the first thing I did to check it was connected and it said it was.

Comment: The processor on the Pi3 and Pi Zero are not compatible. You will need to re-image a separate SD and copy over the web content.

Comment: @RubberStamp really? Where may I read more?

Comment: [Raspberry Pi Hardware](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/README.md) ... The Pi Zero is 32 bit.  The Pi 3 is 64 bit.  So, if you are running the 64 bit kernel on the Pi 3, it won't boot on the Pi Zero.

Comment: So I have a backup image of my OS from my pi 3, would I be able to image that file and shove it onto the pi zero @RubberStamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened was that the pi 3 used a 64 bit kernel which didn't allow the zero w to boot.

I made an image of the SD card,reimaged the SD card, plugged it in, and I now have a working server and ssh port!

Comment: What operating system you are using? It cannot be Raspbian because that's only available in a 32 bit version running on all models.

Comment: It was raspbian, and it did work.